# What to use for creating custom 3D objects and animations?

Tags: animation, model, 3d

I'm used to working with SolidWorks and Catia for 3D object and basic animations but i got a personal project that i work on where i need to build a LASER manufacturing machine and i need to make it look like it is in real life, make zoom inside the machine and see how the light gets polarized as it passes through a crystal, see how the laser beam hits the surface and particles fly of the hit surface,etc.

I thought about Unity Engine but don't know much about this area of 3D and in what program to do the models before importing into Unity, can you guys help me with better solutions ?

Thanks,
Adrian

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Unity, you can import the following file formats: .FBX, .dae, .3DS, .dxf, .obj  (http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-importObject.html)

From Solidworks, you can export as an STL, then import the STL into a 3d Application (ex. Blender), and in Blender you could export the model as an FBX.

Comment: Ty for the information, but what programs to use for animations where can i give an abject movement equations and tell my models how to move ? Unity is just the only one i heard of not necessarily keen on Unity .

Comment: @nairdat What kind of movement? Unity has ways to move your object's transform (http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're able to achieve more in terms of animation with unity. You can design your model documents in SolidWorks or CATIA and save them in IGES (neutral format).

Comment: Ty for the information, but what programs to use for animations where can i give an abject movement equations and tell my models how to move ? Unity is just the only one i heard of not necessarily keen on Unity .